# How does the I/O stream flags work?

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm learning from the LearnCpp website and I came across this line "If an error occurs and a stream is set to anything other than goodbit, further stream operations on that stream will be ignored. This condition can be cleared by calling the clear() function" . However in the ios_base class I noticed that the flags are set static which means they are shared by each instance of the class , Doesn't that mean that if e.g cin sets for exemple the fatalbit flag to true all other instances of istream class won't work ?

Comment: The flags themselves aren't changed, they're static constants. What changes is the underlying bitmask present in each standard stream.

Comment: @0x499602D2 You should post this as the answer because it's correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flags themselves aren't changed, they're static constants. What changes is the underlying bitmask present in each standard stream. What `clear()` does is reset the mask and set the flag that is provided (`ios_base::goodbit` my default).